# How to fix this: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

i am new in using flash and i am trying to create a multiple type quiz game using flash cs5 and as3. in the game, the contents or data are written in an xml file.

i am encountering series of problems and i find it a bit hard in knowing what solution could be used.

1. i have a variable *qno*. qno is used to identify the number of questions that will be called by the program. in my game, i need to output 5 questions. if *qno* reaches 5,the program should call the next frame that will show the scoreboard. my problem is, *qno* does not increment. this problem affects my 3rd problem that i will state later.
   **i have figured out that this is the error that caused the problem:** `TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.` how do i fix this?
2. *SOLVED ^^,(dynamic text caused that problem that affected the questions and choices.but is now fixed*
   i already have said that i am calling the question and the choices in the xml file. the program is calling the code but i have one problem encountered. *it does not show the complete question and choices*. what i meant by that is for example the question is, **how do the birds eat?** when you run the program, it only outputs **how do the b**. it goes the same as the choices. it does not show the complete question and choices.
3. this is not that important yet, but it is about the scoring. i don't know if the program increments the correct and wrong answer variable. but it i already have a code on that. i do know that i have to fix the first problem first before proceeding to this problem.

---

this is the set of codes that i am using

**this is the code used for calling the xml file which is located on frame 1**

```
 var questions:Array=new Array(); 
 var answers:Array=new Array(); 
 var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
 loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadXML);
 loader.load(new URLRequest("sample.xml"));
 function loadXML(e:Event):void 
 { 
var myxml = new XML(e.target.data);
var loop =myxml.ques.length();
for (var i=0;i<loop;i++)
{
    questions[i]=myxml.ques[i].q1;
    answers[i]=[myxml.ques[i].op1,myxml.ques[i].op2,myxml.ques[i].op3];
}
gotoAndPlay(2);
 }
 stop();
```

**this is the main code where the problem is located**

```
 var qno=0;
 var rnd1; 
 var rnd2;
 tick.visible=false;
 cross.visible=false;
 var right_answers=0;
 var wrong_answers=0;
 function change_question()
 {
if(tick.visible)
{
    right_answers++;
}
if(cross.visible)
{
    wrong_answers++;
}
if(qno==1)
{
    gotoAndPlay(3);
}
else
{
    tick.visible=false;
    cross.visible=false;
    rnd1=Math.ceil(Math.random()*3);
    rnd2=Math.ceil(Math.random()*questions.length)-1;
    q.text=questions[rnd2];
    if(questions[rnd2]=="x")
    {   
        change_question();
    }
    questions[rnd2]="x";
    enable_disable(1);
    if(rnd1==1)
    {
        opt1.text=answers[rnd2][0];
        opt2.text=answers[rnd2][1];
        opt3.text=answers[rnd2][2];
    } 
    if(rnd1==2)
    {
        opt1.text=answers[rnd2][2];
        opt2.text=answers[rnd2][0];
        opt3.text=answers[rnd2][1];
    } 
    if(rnd1==3)
    {
        opt1.text=answers[rnd2][1];
        opt2.text=answers[rnd2][2];
        opt3.text=answers[rnd2][0];
    } 
}
 }
 function enable_disable(a)
 { 
if(a==0)
{
    shade1.mouseEnabled=false;
    shade2.mouseEnabled=false;
    shade3.mouseEnabled=false;
} 
if(a==1)
{
    shade1.mouseEnabled=true;
    shade2.mouseEnabled=true;
    shade3.mouseEnabled=true;
}
 }
 change_question();
 next_b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonAction1);
 function ButtonAction1(eventObject:MouseEvent) 
 {
qno++;
change_question();
 } 
 shade1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonAction2); 
 shade2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonAction3); 
 shade3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonAction4); 
 function ButtonAction2(eventObject:MouseEvent)
 {
enable_disable(0);
if(rnd1==1)
{
    tick.visible=true;
    tick.y=shade1.y;
}
else
{
    cross.visible=true;
    cross.y=shade1.y;
}
 }
 function ButtonAction3(eventObject:MouseEvent)
 {
enable_disable(0);
if(rnd1==2)
{
    tick.visible=true;
    tick.y=shade2.y;
}
else
{
    cross.visible=true;
    cross.y=shade2.y;
}
 }
 function ButtonAction4(eventObject:MouseEvent)
 {
enable_disable(0);
if(rnd1==3)
{
    tick.visible=true;
    tick.y=shade3.y;
}
else
{
    cross.visible=true;
    cross.y=shade3.y;
}
 }
 stop();
```

i hope someone could help me solve my problem or what is causing the problem to act that way.

Answer (score 0):

Learning to test & debug is essential when you develop in Actionscript 3 ( or any other language actually ).

Since you're new to Flash, go step by step. 
When you create a new function , test it first , make sure that it returns the expected result, then move on.

It should be as basic as doing this:

```
function init():void
{
      trace('the init function was called, hooray! ;)');
}
```

Also , AS3 is a strongly typed language , so make sure that your variables are typed

```
 //for example
 var myxml:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
```

Before calling the loop, check that you do have a value!

```
 var loop:int =myxml.ques.length();
 if ( loop > 0 )
     trace("loop =" , loop );
 else
     trace('loop = 0, i will not increment!!!');
```

etc...

Hope this helps!

Comment: i already checked the codes earlier and retyped it. i found out that the real problem causing the program is the increment function. qno, wont increment

Comment: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at quiz_fla::MainTimeline/change_question()
 at quiz_fla::MainTimeline/ButtonAction1()

Comment: This simply means that you're trying to access an object that hasn't yet been instantiated or has a null value... probably caused by "tick" or "cross"

Comment: sir @PatrickS, "tick" and "cross" are the name instances of a certain object in the code. tick appears when the answer is correct thus cross appears when the answer is wrong. sorry if you misunderstood it :(  i think the cause of error is in this code `if(qno==1)
{
    gotoAndPlay(3);
}`

Comment: this might help also, this is i think the first reason for the error `function ButtonAction1(eventObject:MouseEvent) 
{
 qno = qno + 1;
 change_question();
}` it proceeds to the next question when the button is clicked but it does not increment which causes the said error i mentioned earlier. i am still trying to find a solution to my problem but i would still appreciate your help sir :(

Comment: Here you assume that the problem is at a specific place as opposed to testing every part of your application to find the error. My approach may be boring but it works... I understand what tick & cross are , I suppose these objects are on the stage, but in your code they appear as non instantiated objects... don't call me sir :)))

Comment: What do you think is the best solution on tick and cross?

Comment: If you're still getting the null error, one thing that might be helpful is to run the Flash file in debug mode by going Debug > Debug Movie. That will give you the line where the error is occuring.